# How to access a different formats within an icns file (Apple Icon Image format)

Tags: cocoa, icons, core-foundation

does anyone know how to access different formats of an icns file?
For example this file contains multiple sizes of the same icon:

[image: icn file with different sizes]

In some cases I just want the large one and in other cases I want the small one.
I couldn't find something in Cocoa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `NSImage` is a container for `NSImageRep`s. When you load an icns file, you get an image containing an `NSBitmapImageRep` for each size in the file. You can iterate over the image’s `representations` property to access them. (Also, the image will automatically choose the most appropriate rep when drawing.)

Comment: Thax a lot! That works.    I am using NSBitmapImageRep *bits = [[myImage representations] objectAtIndex: 2];